# PHP code in Sass source code

Tags: php, css, sass

I'm just learning Sass and trying to figure out my workflow. Problem is that many times I have PHP-code in my CSS-files (autoversioning, path-variables etc). Is there any way of skipping PHP code in SASS (SCSS-files).

EDIT: I have to clarify that the problematic CSS-files are indeed dynamic, so my example.css.php -file runs some PHP and depends on webserver state somehow. (There are no problems with static CSS-files).

If I create simple SCSS-file, I get an error for PHP-code. Any ideas?... has someone made any modifications for Sass-parser to skip script code in sass?

Example test.scss:

```
$backg: #fa0;

#wrapper {
  color: #000;
  background-color: $backg;
}

<?php echo ""; ?>
```

EDIT: One "hack" occurred to my mind. I could use SASS /* */ comments to comment out all PHP-code lines and use some script afterwards to strip out the comment characters and reveal PHP to get correct results...

E.g.

```
// This is an example SCSS-snippet with commented PHP code lines in it...
.foo {
  color: $someColor;
  /* background: transparent url(<?php echo autoVer('../', 'img/badge.png'); ?>) no-repeat center top; */
```

Answer (score 1):

By default your Web-server will not process css/scss files like php. 
You can configure it in Nginx/Apache settings, but it's black coding actually

Answer (score 1):

PHP usually expands a file in context of a specific HTTP request.  The SCSS->CSS conversion usually happens on static files.  Do you want your SCSS depend on data coming from the user, or the web session?  If so, you would have to run Sass after running PHP to get CSS, otherwise your best approach would probably be adding a Makefile rule for running foo.scss.php through PHP and then Sass.

I should also point out that there's a good chance that what you're doing to your CSS with PHP is easily done with SCSS, anyway, so you may not need PHP once the conversion is complete.

Comment: Yes, my styles depend on web server / application state somehow. So they are dynamic...